# Converting WAV to any compressed audio format in client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wav, audio-recording, getusermedia

I am recording audio from `getUserMedia({audio:true});` in the browser using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and then exporting it as a WAV file because that's the only option the library provides.

A 1 minute 20 seconds file is 14.1 MB large. I need to upload the audio to a server and I need to do it fast. How do I convert the WAV audio in any other compressed format to lower the file size?

I don't mind converting to:

- MP3
- Opus
- WebM
- Ogg
- FLAC
- any other format you know of

If there is no way as of now to convert to any of these formats, how can I compress the WAV file on the client?

PS: I did a lot of searches to find anything that converts WAV in JS, but found nothing. [libmp3lame.js](https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js) isn't working in Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507799/convert-wav-to-ogg-on-app-engine-or-in-javascript -- I'm having essentially the same problem, and I really hope someone answers your question.

Comment: I saw your question yesterday. For me the file size is too big so uploading it to the server and converting it there is not a viable option. For your case, if you want to upload and then convert, using a VM is the best option.

Comment: @ArjunBajaj did you find a solution to this? I am interested if you did.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've made an audio recorder that records to mp3 directly from the browser combining RecorderJS and libmp3lame.js

You can find the gitHub project here:
https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js

and a more detailed explanation of the implementation:
http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU. I wish I could upvote this 1000 times

Comment: @Remus Negrota, This works on Chrome, but hangs on Firefox. My research found, something goes infinite loop in the **libmp3lame.min.js** in Firefox. Are you using a modified version of libmp3lame.min.js?

Answer (score 4):

What you really want is the mediaStream "Recording API", which is currently being worked on.  Until that's available, I advise using emscriptem on C/C++ source, and consider running it in a webworker to avoid blocking the UI and other tabs.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and 
came up with quite a quick and dirty solution:

- **zip the wav-file** with zip.js (works with Chrome, Firefox, Safari 6 and Internet Explorer 10)

Further intel see [Documentation zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)

At least this is reducing size a lot, file is about >75% smaller  so **1:4 compression**

**UPDATE: Maybe have a look at this: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/**

It is a Chat Application for Chrome and Firefox developed by google, I assume with kind of CC-License

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (also using recorder.js) and have managed to resolve using the superb [videoconverter.js](https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js) project which includes a port of ffmpeg to Javascript using emscripen. Downside to this is the ffmpeg.js file is about 25Mb.

I modified the existing `exportWAV` function in recorderWorker.js to return both a WAV (for HTML5 `<audio>` playback) and a Blob containing an encoded MP2 file:

```
function encodeWAV(samples) {

  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* ... various writing methods */

  return { wavdata: new Blob([buffer], { type: "audio/wav" }), mp2data: ffmpeg_convert(buffer) };
}

function ffmpeg_convert(buffer) {
    console.log("starting mp2 conversion");
    var args = "-i input -f mp2 output.mp2";
    var results = ffmpeg_run({
        arguments: args.split(" "),
        files: [
          {
              data: new Uint8Array(buffer),
              "name": "input"
          }
        ]
    });
    if (results) {
        var file = results[0];
        console.log("File recieved", file.name, file.data);
        return new Blob([file.data], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method can be used to encode the WAV to any codec suppored by ffmpeg's `libavcodec`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve compression using [opus.js](https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample),

you can find my implementation here: [recordOpus](https://github.com/mido22/recordOpus), but there is a catch, mine is coupled with server-side, and I use `node.js` server....