# HTML5 audio recording in MP3 format

Tags: html5-audio

**I need to record audio through the HTML5, but you need to write directly in MP3**. The reason is that in the standard version of the sound is written in WAV, 5 minutes = 500Mbit - this is a very high resolution. Write to WAV and then recode also tried (and client-side and server-side) - it is a very expensive process and takes a lot of time and resources (5 minutes of recording time is 5 minutes).

**I need to write the sound directly into the format of MP3, convert for me is not suitable**.I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting WAV to any compressed audio format in client-side JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457029/converting-wav-to-any-compressed-audio-format-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: where does the output audio file wind up ? server or browser side ?  I believe mp3 encoding is patent encumbered so firefox wouldn't touch it with a barge pole